# How two websites can use OAuth2 to interact each other?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm trying to understand exactly how works the OAuth2 protocol.

I'm looking for tutorials but i only find tutorials about OAuth2 with Google API, Facebook API or Twitter API.

That's not really what i'm seeking to do.

It's true, i am using the Google App engine, but i don't want to use OAuth2 to access to the Google API data.

I want to know how a small website powered by google App Engine can use the OAuth2 to give and get access  from another small website (App engine or not).

I don't know how to generate an access token and all these required stuffs for authentication.

Facebook API and Twitter etc. All have a UI where the user can interact and click on some button and fill a form to create a OAuth application.

But i want to do all these step for my website but i don't want to create a User Interface, so how doing this programatically by using JAVA or Nodejs ?

Thanks you.

Comment: too broad and not specific to appengine.

Comment: @ZigMandel Ok but let's say i want to access some data in another website by Using Oauth 2. what is the simplest way to do it programmatically ?

Comment: thereare many pages that document or have tutorials for implementing the oauth protocol. show us what you tried so far and what when wrong, else its too broad, sorry.